# Why I'm getting The method rectangle(Mat, Point, Point, Scalar) is undefined for the type Core in openCV 3?

Tags: java, opencv, opencv3.0

I'm trying to follow [THIS](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html#java-dev-intro) simple JAVA tutorial that detects a face and draws a rectangle, but at this line of code:

`Core.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),new Scalar(0, 255, 0));`

I'm getting the following error:

`The method rectangle(Mat, Point, Point, Scalar) is undefined for the type Core`

I'm using `openCV 3` and it seems that the `rectangle` method is removed, or changed, but there is no documentation.

Can someone give me a push? I know that I'm missing an extremely small point here, but I'm unable to spot it.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like in OpenCV 3.0 `rectangle` function moved to `imgproc` module. Try following:

```
Imgproc.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
```

See more details in [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/drawing_functions.html?highlight=rectangle).

Answer (score 2):

Try `Core.rectangle(...);` instead of `Imgproc.rectangle(...)`. I think they change the class of rectangle.

Comment: the other way round ;)